# How can I use Turkish character with XPath's translate() function?

Tags: selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

I need a select element by xpath with text. In this case it should be case-insensitive. I added Turkish characters `(Ç,Ö,İ,Ş,Ü,Ğ)` in translate() function but its not working. Same method working properly with English words.

```
/a[.=translate('seni çok seviyorum','abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrsştuüvwxyz','ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTUÜVWXYZ')]
```

is there a solution to this?

Comment: I don't quite understand the point of the example, i.e. why you don't just use `/a[.='SENİ ÇOK SEVİYORUM']`, but maybe it's just a made-up example and not really your production code. I think the `translate` function in XPath 1 really _should_ work with any Unicode character that's allowed in XML

Comment: Yes, you're right, there was a problem with my use of xpath. Its working good with this;`/a[translate(normalize-space(), 'ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTUÜVWXYZ', 'abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrsştuüvwxyz')='seni çok seviyorum']`